# Common ScrollViewer for multiple datagrid in a Screen

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have three user controls(all of them are dynamically created DataGrids) inside my main screen[image]

i am trying to get a single scroll bar for all the three datagrids . the datagrids is created dynamically and it can be of different coloumns. So my requirement says that all datagrids should have same size. that means if datagrid2 is of bigger size, other two datagrids should grow to match with the datagrid2's size.

Here is how the basic xaml structure.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" 
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <Grid MinWidth="400">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<userControl1/>
<userControl2 Grid.Row="1"/>
<userControl3 Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of thing where [SharedSizeGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx) comes to the rescue.

Try something like this;

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <Grid MinWidth="400">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
         <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
         <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <userControl1/>
      <userControl2 Grid.Row="1"/>
      <userControl3 Grid.Row="2"/>

   </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: tried .. this is sharing the height of row as well :(

Comment: @Peekay I thought that was your whole goal? Are you talking about just having the columns of each datagrid consume full width? If that's the case just set them to stretch and add `Width="*"` to each column. I must be missing something here. :/

Comment: Yup i am just looking for the width. sorry if my question is not clear enough. i will check with Width="*"